# Child page for every category Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I create in my wordpress theme template page named popular.php, where i sort post by popularity. It works fine for every post but I dont know how to do this for category.

I want something like this:

**sitename.com/popular-post** - works fine

**sitename.com/category-name/popular-post** - i don't know how to make popular page child for every category?

Popular loop works fine with this args:

```
<?php $current_category_ID =  getCurrentCatID(); ?>
 <?php $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 60,
      'cat' => $current_category_ID,
      'meta_key' => 'views',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'DESC',
 ); ?>

 <?php query_posts($args); ?>
```

Only I don't know make it child for category?

Comment: check permalink structure

Answer (score 0):

Check Permalink Settings & update the custom structure like this

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: login to your wp admin dashboard & check settings tab, under settings>permalinks> put above code in custom structue then update permalink structure.

Comment: But popular page isn't a post it is a custom page

Comment: Maybe i should do this in other way. For example create a new custom page for popularcategory, but how to make it child for category page?

Comment: i am not getting your above mentioned point,can please tell me the exact issue so that i can suggest something

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

See this page in the codex. It explains how to name your template files for category.

For example, if you have a file in your theme named category.php, that template will be used to display a category page.